# How do you extract 'miles' from a Mapbox directions container and create separate container with miles?

Tags: containers, mapbox

'I am trying to separate the Miles from a mapbox directions container to use in another area. I just downloaded mapbox and I am searching everywhere to find out how to see where the data is so I can extract it but I cant find help with it. This is my code.  I found out how to extract the directions from the map container and now I want to extract the mileage from the directions container.'

```
var plugin = new MapboxDirections({
accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
profile: "mapbox/driving"
}); 

//add direction plug in to an existing div 
document.getElementById('directions').appendChild(plugin.onAdd(map))
////////// THIS IS MY ATTEMPT BELOW TO GET MILES///////////////
document.getElementById('directions.routes[0].distance').appendChild(plugin.onAdd(map))      

//       
map.on('load',  function() {

plugin.setOrigin([-119.05717, 35.42026]); // can be address in form setOrigin("12, Elm Street,    NY")
plugin.setDestination([-119.149330, 35.382359]); // can be address

// THIS IS WHAT I TRIED TO GET MILES ////////////////////////////
var miles = directions.routes[0].distance;
alert(miles);


})
//
```

'I tried document.getElementById('directions.routes[0].distance').appendChild(plugin.onAdd(map)) but I dont know if I am even calling the right field  because I dont know where to get all the fields to call.'

[Mapbox directions: how to extract directions data from result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236016/mapbox-directions-how-to-extract-directions-data-from-result)

'I read this above post and tried what they posted....but failed to get any results from using the console.dir.  And that could be because I am not using that right as well.'
/// their post

'When "opening" the whole route object in the console (via console.dir) I see the directions data I am looking for:'

directions:Object
destination:Object
origin:Object
routes:Array[2]
0:Object
distance:10460
duration:862
geometry:Object
steps:Array[26]
...

///